# Change times of a reservation (timestamp) using Listbox in GWT

Tags: date, gwt, listbox

I want to implement a function (with GWT) to change the start- and end-date/time of a reservation!

The start- & end-date of the reservation is saved as a timestamp.

The reservations are saved in a mySQL DB.

The user can choose the day in a datepicker:

```
final DatePicker chooseDay = new DatePicker();
```

..

```
Date startDate = reservation.getStartDate();
```

..

```
chooseDay.setValue(startDate);
```

..

2 ListBoxes:

```
final ListBox startTime = new ListBox();
final ListBox endTime = new ListBox();
```

..

```
startTime.addItem("08:00");
startTime.addItem("08:30");
startTime.addItem("09:00"); (til 18:00)
```

...

```
endTime.addItem("08:00");
endTime.addItem("08:30");
endTime.addItem("09:00"); (til 18:00)
```

I now have the problem, that i don't know how to change between the formats. Reservations are saved as a timestamp, but how can i change just day and hour/minute?

I am a beginner and it would be really nice if you can help me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use can use [JsDate](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsDate.html) on the client side:

```
JsDate jsDate = JsDate.create(startDate.getTime());
int hour = jsDate.getHours();
int mins = jsDate.getMinutes();
```